# Using mongo/morphia to handle a aggregation but got a NullPointerException

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I was trying the mongo morphia and performing a **group** operation in Java.

Here is the api that I called in my code:

> org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.AggregationPipeline.group(String id,
>   Group... groupings)

Here is what i passed into the specified api:

> org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Group.grouping(String name, String
>   sourceField)

```
        AggregationPipeline pipeline = this.dao.getDatastore()
                                        .createAggregation(Myclass.class)
                                        .match(query
                                                .filter("createTime >=", GroupUtil.fromISODate(beginDate + DATE_SUFFIX).getTime())
                                                .filter("createTime <=", GroupUtil.fromISODate(endDate + DATE_SUFFIX).getTime()))
                                        .sort(Sort.ascending("vendor"))
                                        .group(
                                                "vendor", 
                                                grouping("_id","vendor"),
                                                grouping("count", new Accumulator("$sum", 1)));
```

As soon as I run the code block above, I got a *NullPointerException*,

the problem is because i have initialized the first Grouping by passing String sourcefield,

and the group stage processing this Group with Accumulator

which is doesnt exist if you pass in with a String.

So come to the conclusion, i think there is a mistake and user can't even realized before they choose to use this.

Can someone guide me through this and provide some useful information, thanks in advance.

Following is the source code from morphia:

```
@Override
public AggregationPipeline group(final String id, final Group... groupings) {
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$" + id);
    for (Group grouping : groupings) {
        Accumulator accumulator = grouping.getAccumulator();
        group.put(grouping.getName(), new BasicDBObject(accumulator.getOperation(), accumulator.getField()));
    }

    stages.add(new BasicDBObject("$group", group));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: This works in latest version. I have tested it with 1.3.2. Both`"vendor", 
                                                grouping("_id","vendor")` both translate to the  same thing(`{"_id" : "$vendor"}`). It works because one key overwrites the other but you should be using one or the other variation not both.

Comment: @Veeram thanks for comment. I ended up using ...group("vendor", grouping("count"...), by removed the second vendor param and it worked...but still curious why they design that accumulator...